# asp.net ajax clinety side Sys class not working in content page

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I have a masterpage on which script manager has been placed . In my content page

Sys.Application_load and all other client side classes does not work , geeting **object expected javascript error.**

Same thing works in another content page with another master page in same project. 
All dlls & settings in web.config are perfect & working for other pages , except that one.

Plz help !!! I have got stuck!

Comment: Show the code, impossible to evaluate without that.

Answer (score 1):

If other pages work, your problem is most likely in that content page. Be a programmer, debug it. Start taking out pieces of the page until it works and then see what you've taken out. Otherwise we're going to need some code.